# How to create mulitple NetSuite Entity Fields

Tags: netsuite

I have created a bunch of NetSuite Entity Fields through the UI (Customization > List, Records & Fields > Entity Fields > New) in one of our two NetSuite Sandbox instances.

I now need to recreate those same fields in our other sandbox, and then eventually in production.

Rather than input them by hand every time, I'd like to either export/import them, or, script them.  Unfortunately the information provided by NetSuite doesn't seem to cover this (if it does it's **very** hard to find).  For example, the Import CSV functionality doesn't seem to cover Entity Fields, and the "SuiteScript Supported Records" documentation (for 1.0) doesn't seem to cover them either.

Is it possible to export/import Entity Fields either via CSV or script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is by creating a 'SuiteBundle' that packages your customizations, which you can then share with other accounts.

You can view the documentation [here](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_N3363483.html) (Netsuite login required).

Comment: For something like this, I would create the bundle in your Sandbox, install it in the Production account, then dissolve the bundle. If you need to re-install the same fields somewhere, make the re-usable bundle from the Production account rather than from the Sandbox.

Comment: Looks promising.  BTW that link didn't work, but this one does: https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8082/kw/SuiteBundle